# CSS set baseline of inline-block element manually and have it take the expected height

Tags: html, css

I'm designing a sea-sky component. I'd like to have it's baseline at sea-level.

Here's an attempt that's rendering correctly.

```css
.out {
   display:inline-block;
   background-color:yellow;
   padding-bottom:30px; 
}

.outer {
   display:inline-block;
   background-color:cyan;
   width:100px;
   height:100px;
   position:relative;
   bottom:-30px ;
}

.inner {
  position:absolute;
  height:30px;
  background-color:blue;
  bottom:0px;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="out">hello<div class="outer"><div class="inner">
</div></div>foobar</div>
```

The trick here is to set a negative bottom and use a padding to have the .out bottom at the expected position. Here's what happens without the padding.

```css
.out {
   display:inline-block;
   background-color:yellow;
}

.outer {
   display:inline-block;
   background-color:cyan;
   width:100px;
   height:100px;
   position:relative;
   bottom:-30px ;
}

.inner {
  position:absolute;
  height:30px;
  background-color:blue;
  bottom:0px;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="out">hello<div class="outer"><div class="inner">
</div></div>foobar</div>
```

However, using multiple such component would require setting the padding to the max of all the bottom of the components which are on the last line. This is not feasible.

Is there a way to do without the padding-bottom ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you use `bottom: -30px`. Yes, aligns the sea with the text, but breaks the layout.

Instead, you should take advantage of [inline-blocks having a very interesting baseline](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align):

> The baseline of an 'inline-block' is the baseline of its last line box
>   in the normal flow, unless it has either no in-flow line boxes or if
>   its 'overflow' property has a computed value other than 'visible', in
>   which case the baseline is the bottom margin edge.

That is, you only need to fill the sky part with some in-flow content. Since the sea part is already out-of-flow, it won't affect the baseline. Therefore, you can insert a pseudo-element is `.outer` which takes the remaining height left by `.inner`:

```css
.outer::before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: calc(100% - 30px);
}
```

```css
.out {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.outer {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: cyan;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}
.outer::before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: calc(100% - 30px);
}
.inner {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="out">
  hello
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="inner"></div>
  </div>
  foobar
</div>
```

To avoid that `calc(100% - 30px)` you can also use flexbox:

```css
.outer {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.outer::before {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```css
.out {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.outer {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: cyan;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.outer::before {
  content: '';
  flex: 1;
}
.inner {
  height: 30px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="out">
  hello
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="inner"></div>
  </div>
  foobar
</div>
```

But I think the CSS WG hasn't completely decided how baselines in orthogonal flows should behave, so I would recommend `calc(100% - 30px)` for now.

Comment: And consider replacing `.inner` with a `.outer::after` pseudo-element.

Comment: Thanks, I guess that if a CSS-Fu were to be written, that thing should be part of it.

Comment: +1 for `inline-flex`. This effectively removes any line rendering artifacts, which exist with `block` and `inline-block`.